# Code to find peak index of mountain array

Tags: c++, arrays

You may recall that an array A is a mountain array if and only if: `A.length >= 3`

There exists some `i` with `0 < i < A.length - 1` such that:

```
A[0] < A[1] < ... A[i-1] < A[i]
A[i] > A[i+1] > ... > A[A.length - 1]
```

**NOTES**:

- Array can be accessed using `arr.get(index)` function and its `length = arr.length()`.
- Test case it is failing is : `(3,5,3,2,0)`.
- Error : control reaches end of non void function.

**My take**:
I want to use binary search (with some modifications) to find the peak. Keeping in mind the above given conditions of mountain array, only 3 possibilities are there i.e. (point of increasing slope, point on peak, point on decreasing slope)

**CODE**:

```
int getPeak(MountainArray &arr, int left, int right)
{
  int mid;
  int mid_num;
  int after_mid, before_mid;

  mid = (left + right) / 2;
  if (mid == 0)
  {
    return getPeak(arr, mid + 1, right);
  } // to make sure i dont violate the range of array by calculating before_mid.mid_num = arr.get(mid);
  after_mid = arr.get(mid + 1);
  before_mid = arr.get(mid - 1);

  if (before_mid < mid_num && mid_num < after_mid)
  {
    return getPeak(arr, mid + 1, right);
  }

  else if (mid_num > after_mid && mid_num > before_mid)
  {
    return mid;
  }

  else if (mid_num > after_mid && mid_num < before_mid)
  {
    return getPeak(arr, left, mid - 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: I got the error , i jjust had to change last else if to else as the compiler was seaching for an else condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't initialize `mid_num`, which causes *undefined behavior*. Add:

```
mid_num = arr.get(mid);  // missing
after_mid = ...
...
```

BTW, when you find the *local* peak (second branch), you might want to additionally check that it is a global peak as well. As written, it would return index 2 for this array: `{5,2,4,2,5}`, which is not a mountain according to your definition.

Comment: Yeah that was my mistake too. It is clear from the definition that only one peak will be there.